# Error CS1978: Cannot use an expression of type 'uint*' as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, dynamic, unsafe

I have code that looks like the following:

```
    public void GetData(dynamic dObj)
    {
        unsafe
        {
            byte[] myBuffer = new byte[255];
            uint myBufferCount = 0; 
            fixed (byte* myBufferPointer = myBuffer)
            {
                dObj.GetDatas(myBufferPointer, &myBufferCount);
            }
        }
    }
```

The idea is to call a function that will exist called "GetDatas", which takes a buffer and a count as pointers.  However, this triggers the following error:

> Error CS1978: Cannot use an expression of type 'uint*' as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation

I can't find any further information on this error or how to resolve it.  The MSDN docs seem unhelpful, as they do not seem to contain this error message at all.  What is going wrong here?  How do I dynamically call a function with the signature:

```
 void MyFunc(byte *buffer, uint *count);
```

?

Comment: I never used pointers along with dynamics but having tried to use them along with generics the basic conclusion I came to is that nobody on the C# team cares about pointers or unsafe code interaction with new features. And related documentation is completely unhelpful.

Comment: My guess is that the base of the problem is section 25.1.1 of the csharp spec and clarified latter "In unsafe code (§27), a type-argument shall not be a pointer-type" as the DLR internally uses expression trees a lot at some point an Expression<Action<byte*, uint*>> might have to be created and it won't work.

Comment: @Virtual - which version of the spec are you referencing? I'm looking in 4.0, and its sections only seem to go up to 18.

Comment: I found something similar to VirtualBlackFox, but in the 4.0 spec, I'm looking in section 18.2: "A pointer-type cannot be used as a type argument (§4.4), and type inference (§7.5.2) fails on generic method calls that would have inferred a type argument to be a pointer type."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever ECMA - 334 from http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf but that's only a guess that it is the source of the problem.

Comment: @VirtualBlackFox: It has nothing to do with whether I care about it or not. The CLR does not allow pointer types to be used as type arguments, and the dynamic code is heavily dependent on passing information about the call site to the DLR using type arguments.

Comment: @Eric Lippert : Sorry to have targeted the C# team  if it's a CLR limitation (And I didn't target you directly). I wrote to fast and should have guessed it (or just read the spec). Well i guess that even the fact that generic constraints can't contain something like "could-sizeof" is a limitation of the CLR not a will of the C# team.

Comment: @Eric Lippert : Also while I found this limitations often problematic when dealing with interop with C I totally understand that the number of person it affect is too small and the needed changes to broad to be interesting for Microsoft to implement. Especially considering that while it can't be used on Mono and isn't an open standard C++ .Net is a perfect candidate for such interop code for a pure-Microsoft shop; Making further development of the unsafe part of C# less interesting for Microsoft.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text from that error message is my own, and the story is that you cannot mix pointer-types and dynamic dispatch, period. Why?

The underlying reason is that pointers cannot be boxed. The fact that they cannot be used as type arguments is a bit of a red herring, since we are perfectly OK with "ref" types as dynamic arguments, and those can't be used as type arguments either. The compiler emits new delegate types to deal with ref types and it could probably do so to generate code in your assembly that creates a call site against a signature that has pointer-type parameters.

But back to the issue. Since pointers cannot be boxed, you can never have a pointer value in "dynamic," which means you can never really dynamically dispatch on a pointer. Also, since return values from dynamic calls are boxed, you cannot dynamically dispatch to a function that returns a pointer.

And so, in one respect you can think of this as one of those decisions that simplifies an issue for the user. It it a little complicated to say, ok, here are a few things you can do with pointers and dynamic, and there are some things you might be able to get away with for a while, so try to keep them straight. It's much easier to say (and remember) "no pointers with dynamic at all."

There is another issue, which I have to admit my memory is a little fuzzy on. Even if we did allow you to do this, the DLR would have to allow it. And when we were implementing C# 4.0, the DLR was a moving target, which meant the DLR and the C# runtime were really both moving targets. At various points, either one of those components were trying to box arguments for various reasons. I cannot recall what we shipped and whether that still happens, but anyway at least at some point in time this was a consideration.

It turns out "pointers occasionally with dynamic" is a feature that the various teams involved did not think was a very high priority. Which, of course, does not imply that we thought unsafe code in general is not high priority.

EDIT: I can't find any mention of this in the language specification. That is a spec bug. I'll make sure it gets reported.

EDIT EDIT: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/653347/c-language-spec-ommission-cannot-mix-pointer-types-with-dynamic-dispatch

Comment: Just decompiled a dynamic call with a ref parameter and yes the solution is really simple, I don't know why I believed that the DLR was more tied to Action/Func delegate types but I need clearly to read more on this. Regarding boxing and boxed-pointers it might be solved with a marker type say Pointer<Pointer<int>> for int** and boxing that but the complexity/cost of this is high (For example what security holes or even just potential problems it might include in silverlight...). Again sorry for my comment targeting the csharp team I didn't realize that I sounded so harsh.

Comment: Ben, yes, there are any number of strategies one can use to get a pointer value on the heap, including boxing an IntPtr, but that doesn't change the fact that you can't box a pointer. And anyway, if you do one of these things then you've collapsed some user intent, such as whether the user wanted to do a thing with an IntPtr or with a pointer. And then you need more mechanism to determine which it was, in code, which may not always even be possible (what does the call site know about return values?). It's all too complicated, and this scenario, as I said, is not a very high priority.

Answer (score 3):

As specified in my comment my guess is that the base of the problem is section 25.1.1 of the csharp spec and clarified latter

> In unsafe code (§27), a type-argument shall not be a pointer-type

as the DLR internally uses expression trees a lot at some point an `Expression<Action<byte*, uint*>>` might have to be created and it won't work.

---

I repeated my comment here just to be able to post some code, as one of the solution might be to use IntPtr. It works but you lose part of the type info so I don't know if it's really useful.

It avoid loosing type safety creating an `IntPtr<T>` struct may allow to use dynamics, in this case the T type would only be a marker for the DLR. But maybe it's overkill to do this just to be able to use the DLR with pointers.

```
void Main()
{
    unsafe
    {
        var inst = new TestClass();
        byte* test = stackalloc byte[5];

        uint count;
        inst.Test(test, &count);
    }

    unsafe
    {
        dynamic inst = new TestClass();
        byte* test = stackalloc byte[5];

        uint count;
        inst.Test(new IntPtr(test), new IntPtr(&count));
    }   
}

class TestClass
{
    public unsafe void Test(IntPtr buffer, IntPtr count)
    {
        Test((byte*)buffer.ToPointer(), (uint*)count.ToPointer());
    }

    public unsafe void Test(byte* buffer, uint* count)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message strongly suggests that approach simply isn't going to work. You may have to use either static binding (perhaps to an interface that declares `void GetDatas(byte *buffer, uint *count)`), or manual reflection.

Comment: That seems entirely possible, but it'd be nice to have some sort of supporting documentation SOMEWHERE explaining this limitation :\